# Unity App: Unfortunately App Has Stopped Working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have been looking a lot of places for the solution to an "Unfortunately App Has Stopped Working" crash and not been able to find a suitable answer to solve.

My Unity Android app starts and plays normally for a long time and then when I load a new scene it stops.  The scene itself is using the same assets as in previous scenes.  Perhaps it's in the code?  Where do I start looking for possible suspects?

Device Filter: FAT (ARMv7 + x86)
Graphics APIs: OpenGLE2

The Logcat has been copied and hoping someone can spot something I may have missed.

```
12-03 18:36:17.126  1350  2738 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
12-03 18:36:17.136   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.146   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 E Zygote  : v2
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 I libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10321
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 W SELinux : Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0004
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 I libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 E Zygote  : accessInfo : 0
12-03 18:36:17.146  5616  5616 W SELinux : SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.156  5616  5616 I art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-03 18:36:17.156  1350  1449 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{c225be9 u0 d0 Application Error: com.megaworldstudios.omegatech}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
12-03 18:36:17.156  1350  2738 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5616:com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/u0a321 for activity com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
12-03 18:36:17.156   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.156  1350  1449 D ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
12-03 18:36:17.156   652   652 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb60a8
12-03 18:36:17.166   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.166   652  2767 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1752 Removed ClurSurface (14/16)
12-03 18:36:17.166   652   652 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1773 createSurf (16x16),-1 flag=20004, EimSurface
12-03 18:36:17.166   652   674 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1752 Removed ClurSurface (-2/17)
12-03 18:36:17.176   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.176  1350  1449 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{c225be9 u0 d0 Application Error: com.megaworldstudios.omegatech}: mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
12-03 18:36:17.176   652   652 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb60a8
12-03 18:36:17.186   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.196   940  1453 V audio_hw_primary: out_get_latency: Latency 80
12-03 18:36:17.196  5616  5616 D TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
12-03 18:36:17.196  5616  5616 D ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
12-03 18:36:17.206   940  1375 I APM::AudioPolicyManager: stopOutput() output 2, stream 3, session 2753
12-03 18:36:17.206  1350  3208 D ActivityManager:  Launching com.megaworldstudios.omegatech, updated priority
12-03 18:36:17.216  2352  2352 V CenterBarWindowService: noteResumeComponent  /arrangeState : 0
12-03 18:36:17.226  5616  5616 D ContextRelationManager: ContextRelationManager() : FEATURE_ENABLED=true
12-03 18:36:17.226  5616  5616 D RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
12-03 18:36:17.226  5616  5616 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.megaworldstudios.omegatech-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.megaworldstudios.omegatech rsrc of package com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.236  1350  3348 I InjectionManagerService -AppFeature: getCoreFeaturePkgList :[]
12-03 18:36:17.236  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
12-03 18:36:17.236  5616  5616 D ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
12-03 18:36:17.246  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 D InjectionManager: InjectionManager
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 D InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: Constructor com.megaworldstudios.omegatech, Feature store :{}
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.megaworldstudios.omegatech-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.megaworldstudios.omegatech rsrc of package com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 D RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
12-03 18:36:17.256  5616  5616 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.megaworldstudios.omegatech-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.megaworldstudios.omegatech rsrc of package com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.266  5616  5616 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.megaworldstudios.omegatech time:1128729753
12-03 18:36:17.266  1350  3206 D VirtualScreenPolicy: applyVirtualScreenAttrs attrs=VirtualScreenAttrs{mDisplayId=0, mBaseDisplayId=0, mBaseActivity=false}
12-03 18:36:17.266  1350  3206 D GameManagerService: identifyGamePackage. com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.266  1350  3206 D MultiWindowPolicy: Gamemode - return 0,  when calling  identifyForegroundApp(com.megaworldstudios.omegatech)
12-03 18:36:17.266  1350  3206 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1350  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
12-03 18:36:17.276  1350  3206 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1350  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
12-03 18:36:17.276  1350  3206 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.acquire()
12-03 18:36:17.276  1350  3206 V WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{d092de634 token=Token{1793507 ActivityRecord{905ff46 u0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t111}}} to stack=2 task=111 at 1
12-03 18:36:17.276  1350  3206 D InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
12-03 18:36:17.286  5616  5616 D Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
12-03 18:36:17.286  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity isFragment :false
12-03 18:36:17.316  5616  5616 D SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
12-03 18:36:17.326  5616  5616 D ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{e22a5f5 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-03 18:36:17.326  1350  2715 D ISSUE_DEBUG: InputChannelName : 90d1159 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
12-03 18:36:17.326  1350  3208 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() false
12-03 18:36:17.326  1350  3208 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: postActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
12-03 18:36:17.326  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: handleActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
12-03 18:36:17.326  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: Shared devices show user statefalse
12-03 18:36:17.346  2352  2352 V CenterBarWindowService: noteResumeComponent  /arrangeState : 0
12-03 18:36:17.346   652   652 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1774 createSurf (1x1),2 flag=404, VnityPlayer
12-03 18:36:17.356  1350  1442 E libprocessgroup: failed to kill 1 processes for processgroup 4965
12-03 18:36:17.366  5616  5616 D RelationGraph: garbageCollect()
12-03 18:36:17.366  5616  5616 W ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.megaworldstudios.omegatech-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.megaworldstudios.omegatech rsrc of package com.megaworldstudios.omegatech
12-03 18:36:17.386  5616  5616 I Unity   : splash_mode = 0 (integer)
12-03 18:36:17.386  5616  5616 I Unity   : useObb = False (bool)
12-03 18:36:17.426   974   974 I Zygote  : Process 4965 exited due to signal (11)
12-03 18:36:17.426  1350  2102 E         : BitTube(): close sendFd (417)
12-03 18:36:17.466  1350  2213 D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.megaworldstudios.omegatech    className : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
12-03 18:36:17.566  1350  2213 I MdnieScenarioControlService: mGameModeLauncher : false
12-03 18:36:17.566  1350  2213 I MdnieScenarioControlService: setUIMode
12-03 18:36:17.576  5616  5616 D Unity   : surfaces: attach glview
12-03 18:36:17.576  5616  5616 D SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
12-03 18:36:17.576  5616  5616 I Unity   : Choreographer available: Enabling VSYNC timing
12-03 18:36:17.586  5616  5616 D Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
12-03 18:36:17.586  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity isFragment :false
12-03 18:36:17.586  5616  5616 I Unity   : onResume
12-03 18:36:17.586  5616  5616 D ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4cc0e2e I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
12-03 18:36:17.586  1350  2748 D ISSUE_DEBUG: InputChannelName : ea1c12a com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity
12-03 18:36:17.586  1350  1399 D ActivityManager: post active user change for 0 fullscreen true isFloatingActivity() false isHomeActivity() false
12-03 18:36:17.586  1350  1399 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: postActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.586  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: handleActiveUserChange [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.586  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: Shared devices show user statefalse
12-03 18:36:17.606  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: dispatchCreateOptionsMenu :com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
12-03 18:36:17.606  5616  5616 I InjectionManager: dispatchPrepareOptionsMenu :com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity
12-03 18:36:17.606  5616  5616 D ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 96 - 0, 0) or=2
12-03 18:36:17.626  1350  2163 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{90d1159 u0 d0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
12-03 18:36:17.636   652   652 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1775 createSurf (2560x1440),1 flag=4, VnityPlayer
12-03 18:36:17.636  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
12-03 18:36:17.636  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is false
12-03 18:36:17.636  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.636   652   652 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb60a8
12-03 18:36:17.646   652   652 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1776 createSurf (2560x1440),2 flag=404, TurfaceView
12-03 18:36:17.646  5616  5616 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0xee2ae608
12-03 18:36:17.646  5616  5616 D Unity   : [EGL] Attaching window :0xee2ae608
12-03 18:36:17.646  1350  3208 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{2fb94b8 u0 d0 SurfaceView}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
12-03 18:36:17.696  1350  2748 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{2fb94b8 u0 d0 SurfaceView}: mDrawState=READY_TO_SHOW
12-03 18:36:17.726  1350  1398 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{ea1c12a u0 d0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: mDrawState=DRAW_PENDING
12-03 18:36:17.726  5616  5616 D ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
12-03 18:36:17.726   652   652 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb60a8
12-03 18:36:17.726  1350  2163 V WindowStateAnimator: Finishing drawing window Window{ea1c12a u0 d0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: mDrawState=COMMIT_DRAW_PENDING
12-03 18:36:17.726  5616  5616 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@53b78a9 time:1128730214
12-03 18:36:17.726  5616  5616 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@d6e1bef time:1128730214
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1449 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:830 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.notifyToSSRM:8587 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.access$1500:304 com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager$PolicyHandler.handleMessage:1206 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1495 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity: +404ms (total +603ms)
12-03 18:36:17.736  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.746   652   676 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1774 Removed VnityPlayer (8/19)
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  1495 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1350  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@18
12-03 18:36:17.746   652  3342 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1774 Removed VnityPlayer (-2/19)
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  3212 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.746  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.756  1350  1495 D ActivityManager: mDVFSHelper.release()
12-03 18:36:17.756  1350  1495 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{d1175fc u0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity t111} time:1128730241
12-03 18:36:17.756   652   652 D libEGL  : eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb6178
12-03 18:36:17.766  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.766  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.766   652   676 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 Removed VnityPlayer (9/18)
12-03 18:36:17.766  1350  1447 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1350  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@24
12-03 18:36:17.766   652   674 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1770 Removed VnityPlayer (-2/18)
12-03 18:36:17.766  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.766   652   674 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 Removed TurfaceView (8/17)
12-03 18:36:17.766   652  3342 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 Removed TurfaceView (-2/17)
12-03 18:36:17.776  1350  1495 D PowerManagerService: [api] [s] wakeUpWithReason (uid: 1000 pid: 1350) eventTime = 1128730260 event = 17
12-03 18:36:17.776   652   652 D libEGL  : eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb61a8
12-03 18:36:17.776   652   652 D libEGL  : eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb61a8
12-03 18:36:17.776  5616  5616 V ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{ef28948 token=android.os.BinderProxy@d6e1bef {com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity}} show : false
12-03 18:36:17.776   652  2767 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1771 Removed TurfaceView (-2/17)
12-03 18:36:17.776  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.776  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:17.776  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:17.806  1350  1360 I art     : Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 223283(12MB) AllocSpace objects, 75(2MB) LOS objects, 19% free, 62MB/77MB, paused 5.289ms total 150.138ms
12-03 18:36:18.006   652   652 D libEGL  : eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7ff5fb60a8
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1495 I Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{905ff46 u0 com.megaworldstudios.omegatech/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity t111} time:1128730495
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:18.016  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.006  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:18.016  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.016  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.016  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:18.026  1350  1495 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: notifyActivityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.026  1350  1350 D KnoxTimeoutHandler: activityDrawn [MsgParam] userId: 0 fullscreen is true showWhenlocked is true
12-03 18:36:18.026  1350  1350 I KnoxTimeoutHandler: SD activityfalse
12-03 18:36:18.076  1350  1350 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: releaseDVFSLockLocked : Getting Lock type frm List : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1555200  uid : 1000  pid : 1350  tag : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@244
```

Comment: are you sure the logcat is from the crash? looks like an unrelated logcat before or after the crash.